# .withMethodCall() chained on a varargs methods ByteBuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm stuck with an error : `LEAST(double[]) does not accept 10 arguments`

My method :     `double Least(double...tab){}`

But when I try to give to this method arguments by other method call :

```
for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++){
    method = method.withMethodCall(methodCall[i])
}
```

I get the previous error because ByteBuddy convert `Least(double ... tab)` to `Least(double[] tab)`
How can I do ? I have to use varargs here...

Answer (score 1):

Varargs are merely cosmetic for javac but have no relevance on the byte code level, your method accepts a single `double[]` and that's what Byte Buddy expects from you. You can explode a parameter array's value by using `withArgumentArrayElements` where you need to specify the argument's parameter index and the array's starting index and length.

Comment: This does not work, I would need a withMethodCallArray() because I get each value of my array with a methodCall.
The only solution that works for the moment is to have the signature with all the parameters.

Comment: Maybe something likie this : 
```method.withMethodCall(convertToArray(methodCalls))```